# AJAX/JQuery and PHP to send prompt without reload for a contact form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Full website: http://adamginther.com

I've used two separate tutorials to build this, one for the PHP and one for the AJAX. My goal is to build a contact form that will check for errors. If there are no errors then it will prompt users with a message saying that the message has been sent without refreshing the page.

When the website is run locally it does not display the errors until the button is pressed, when run on the server the errors are displayed on entering the page. When the contact button is pressed it loads PHP and the page goes blank.

HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<label name="firstName">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
<label class="error" for="firstName" id="name_error">I need your name.</label>
<br id="namebreak">
<br>
<label name="email" for="email" id="email_label">E-mail Address: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<label class="error" for="firstName" id="name_error">I need your e-mail.</label>
<br id="emailbreak">
<br>
<label name="message">Message: </label>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<label class="error" for="firstName" id="name_error">I need your message.</label>
<br id="messagebreak">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Say Hello!" id="contactbutton" class="button">
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function () {

        $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#firstName").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#name").focus();
            $("#namebreak").hide();
            return false;
        }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            $("#emailbreak").hide();
            return false;
        }
        var message = $("input#message").val();
        if (message == "") {
            $("label#message_error").show();
            $("input#message").focus();
            $("#messagebreak").hide();
            return false;
        }

        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('#contactme').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<p>Contact form submitted.</p>")
                    .append("<p>I will get back to you shortly.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500, function () {
                    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$field_firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'gintherthegreat@gmail.com';
$subject = 'AdamGinther.com message from '.$field_firstName;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_firstName."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' .$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#panel').show();
    $('#output-inside').text('Thank you ' + firstName + ', I will get back to you as soon as I can.');
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#panel').show();
    $('#output-inside').text('I am sorry ' + firstName + ', but there was a problem processing your request. I can be contacted by e-mail at GintherTheGreat@Gmail.com');   </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit new to this hence why I used a tutorial to build the two. Would I write "contactbutton.onPress {
}" in my AJAX?

Comment: Perhaps something missed by doing two tutorials. If you're not using the built-in functionality of the 'form' (that is, you're not submitting something immediately) then don't use a form at all. Just use inputs and a button, then put an onclick event on the button, which calls the AJAX, does the checks and sends it to contact.php. I made exactly the same mistake as a beginner.

Comment: that would make sense. I've tried making this change, and it still is not working. The script looks like this:

`$(function() {
 $('.error').hide();
 $('#contactbutton').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();`

[Full website](http://adamginther.com)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prevent default action of the submit button.

Use,

```
$(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       // Other code
     });
});
```

Comment: this did not work. I think there is a problem with my PHP, seeing as this problem does not come up when run locally and I'm very new to PHP.

Comment: You cannot keep same id for more than one element. Here, you have defined the id name 'name_error' for more than one element. First correct it

Comment: thanks, I copied and pasted that tag and forgot to change the id's. I fixed it and it still is not working.

Comment: @user2376526 Did u hide the errors in CSS or anywhere by default?

Comment: the errors are not displayed when run locally so this isn't the issue. I've tried doing so and it didn't display the errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

change

`<form action="contact.php" method="post">`

to

`<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="form_id">`

and change

`$(".button").click(function () {`
to

```
$('#form_id').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change the button type from submit to button so it will not submit the form and goes to php blank page by default and call the function for u.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a form, why not just have an external .php (e.g. sendmail.php) script that handles your php, and then use jQuery to handle the POST.

```
$.post('sendmail.php',{
   mail:mail,
   message:message
}, function(data) {
   //Echo either "success" or "false" in the sendmail.php script
   if(data == "success"){
      //Do something - e.g. (alert('Message has been sent');)
   }else{
      //Do something
   }
});
```